# Name of electric component

Tags: resistance, conductance

The conductance of a resistor is defined to be 1/R. What is the name of a electric element which obeys this law?

[image]

And how do we draw it in a circuit diagram?

Comment: That's still a resistor. Just re-arranging the equation doesn't change what it is because it's still the same equation which still describes the same behaviour.

Comment: You can call it a *conductor* instead of a resistor of you like. Conventionally we use the symbol *G* for conductance, instead of *k*.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @winny no it isnt homework.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing as a resistor. You are just measuring the resistance differently.

Notice that:

$$I=kV$$ and $$V=I\frac{1}{k}$$

are the same thing and we usually call \$\frac{1}{k}\$ "resistance" and use the letter R.